# navigate to a page from a popup menu?

Tags: windows-phone-7

While working on pop up menu, I am not able to navigate to a different page, other than the parent of the pop up.

How to achieve this in my WP7 app?

Comment: Hey man, you're going to have to put a little more effort into your question.  Please don't use shortenings like 'plz' or 'any1'.  This website is designed as a place for professionals to share their knowledge.  It might seem disrespectful if you don't put as much effort into your question as you expect people to put into their answer.

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by "pop-up menu"? Is it the Application Bar menu or something else?

Answer (score 0):

if it is the `Popup` element, did you do `popup.IsOpen=false` ; where popup is an object of Popup; after navigating??